# CSS Font-face not working

Tags: css, fonts

I've tried this code on my site.

```
<style type="text/css">


@font-face {
    font-family: Eurostyle;
    src: url(http://www.theamazingmonth.pusku.com/eurostyle.ttf);
    font-weight:700;
}

euro {
    font-family: Eurostyle, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: Ebrima;
    src: url(http://www.theamazingmonth.pusku.com/ebrima.ttf);
    font-weight:700;
}

ebrima {
    font-family: Ebrima;
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

But It can't seem to work! Im using dreamweaver to test my code live. On dreamwever it works, but on Chrome doesn't! What could be the problem? you can check the site on theamazingmonth.pusku.com.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why did you obfuscate the URL?

Comment: Please post the HTML that goes with your CSS

Comment: The code posted does not correspond to the code at the URL announced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to create your own elements. There's no such thing as `<euro>` or `<ebrima>`. What you want to do is create a class, thus adding a dot and your rules will end up like this:

```
.ebrima {
    font-family: Ebrima;
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

On elements where you want the Ebrima typeface you'll then add `class="ebrima"` instead of wrapping them with the imaginary element `<ebrima>`.

Comment: Ok, I've tried it and used <class=''ebrima''>text</ebrima> but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I looked at your site. `<class="ebrima">` should be `<span class="ebrima">`, `<span>` is a generic element for text much like `<div>` is for blocks.

Comment: Ah! I got it to work on a html page. It seems that it doesn't work on .php files. Thank you!

Comment: On the page announced, http://theamazingmonth.pusku.com/, there is no Ebrima font declared, and even the Eurostyle font does not work there. What did you actually do, and why was the answer accepted when it does not seem to have solved the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, this will not work in IE<10 (probably). You should use font-face generator, like http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

My font-face syntax:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Eurostyle';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url('[PATH_TO]/Eurostyle.eot');
    src: url('[PATH_TO]/Eurostyle.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('[PATH_TO]/Eurostyle.woff') format('woff'),
     url('[PATH_TO]/Eurostyle.ttf')  format('truetype'),
     url('[PATH_TO]/Eurostyle.svg#[FONT_ID]') format('svg');
}
```

Check this: http://caniuse.com/fontface

Answer (score 0):

you need to add class to your element that you wish to have specified font.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Eurostyle;
    src: url(http://www.theamazingmonth.pusku.com/eurostyle.ttf);
    font-weight:700;
}

.euro {
    font-family: Eurostyle;
    font-size: 24px;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: Ebrima;
    src: url(http://www.theamazingmonth.pusku.com/ebrima.ttf);
    font-weight:700;
}
.ebrima {
    font-family: Ebrima;
    font-size: 24px;
}

<div class="euro">EURO FONT 1234</div>
<div class="ebrima">EBRIMA FONT 1234</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from other problems, the font at http://www.theamazingmonth.pusku.com/eurostyle.ttf is corrupt, as you can see by trying to convert it with FontSquirrel (as you should if you intend to use a font on the web – not all browsers support .ttf fonts). It seems to lack an index that maps character code positions to glyphs. Contact the author or vendor of the font, or use a different font.